# Delete MySql data securely from webpage

Tags: php, mysql, security

I have a webpage where I list all my database data. I have a `DELETE` link in front of each record. When a user click that `DELETE` link, it redirect user to a page called `delete.php` and in this page I run the delete query. My process is

**Index.php**

```
<a href="delete.php?action=delete&id=<?php echo $ID; ?>">DELETE</a>
```

**delete.php**

```
if (isset($_REQUEST["action"]))
if ($_REQUEST["action"] == "delete") {
    $id= $_GET['id'];
    $del_query = mysql_query("DELETE FROM TABLE WHERE id= '$id'");
}
```

Can anyone tell me any secure method of deleting data because this process is not secure and user can directly type this in the URL `delete.php?action=delete&id=3` which will delete that record.

Comment: Have a look at SQL injection page in the comment above.

Comment: @MKhalidJunaid I didn't ask about SQL injection. I want the way to pass ID securely

Comment: @maythesource.com in that question it is not mentioned how to pass id or other data securely.

Comment: *"Can anyone tell me any secure method of deleting data because this process is not secure and user can directly type this in the URL delete.php?action=delete&id=3 which will delete that record."* - Just don't and do use a login method where the verified and trusted user has permission to do so.

Comment: @Fred-ii- in my Query I check user id also but I dont want even a user can delete his own data by typing directly in the URL

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You will need a post method which can't be given directly (by typing the url)

instead this use form

```
<a href="delete.php?action=delete&id=<?php echo $ID; ?>">DELETE</a>

<form method="post" action="delete.php?action=delete">
id: <input type="text" name="id"/> <input type="submit"/>
</form>
```

in delete.php you will need `$id=$_POST['id']`

for more security concern, you will need some type of CAPTCHA technique

Comment: thank you so much for the answer. I was using form but i thought It will load the webpage more

Comment: @sHAmsuLaRiFeEn Although [GET shouldn’t be used for anything other than data retrieval](http://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc2616#section-9.3), simply changing it to POST won’t change anything unless you have a proper authorization check in effect.